# Printing not happening but scanning is fine

Tags: printing

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTE

I was connecting my printer to print

Well drivers installed are ok

Scanning is working

But printing is not happening

Printer is quite old

Model is Canon Imageclass mf4570dw

Thank you

Comment: Did you tell CUPS about your printer? `http://localhost:631` will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Canon provide good support for these very good devices;

If you go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html and click to download and **SAVE** what will be linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz (this version came out 8th Feb this year)

If you open a terminal; copy each command below line by line; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key; move to the next line ..(ask how to open terminal and paste if you don't know)

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz

cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken

sudo ./install.sh
```

that last command runs the install script; that should do all for you; *watch it as it runs*, as it will ask you questions; we hope it all goes well